# HTML input pattern fails

Tags: regex, html, forms, validation

I'm sure I miss something, but can't find the reason why this pattern doesn't work... The validator doesn't accept the format of the string I typed (i.e. 06201234567).

`<input type="tel" pattern="06\d{7,9}" placeholder="06201234567">`

I tried exactly the same code at w3schools' tryit editor, and there were no problem...

Comment: It works well. Did you place between `<form>` and `</form>`?

Comment: Thank you for the quite fast answer :) Yes, I did.
BUT the form is in a template where I replaced some texts like {{example}} with other texts. I don't know how, but php's preg_replace() search expression {{.*?}} matced {7,9}, but ({{.*?}}) didn't...

Comment: Looks like you have not posted all the relevant code. Please add that code to the question.

Comment: First save the page html (generated by php or ...) and check the all blocks and tags. May be there is a bug about form tag. also you can check it with browser inspector.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML5 you can use `<input type='tel'> and <input type='email'>`

You can also specify a specific pattern like `<input type='tel' pattern='[\+]\d{2}[\(]\d{2}[\)]\d{4}[\-]\d{4}' title='Phone Number (Format: +99(99)9999-9999)'>`

Something like `pattern='^\+?\d{0,13}'` Would give you an optional + and up to 13 digits

Answer (score 0):

The form is in a template where I replaced some texts like `{{example}}` with other texts and php's `preg_replace()` search expression `{{.*?}}` matched `{7,9}` in the pattern and replaced it.

With the use of `({{.*?}})` everything's OK.